# Найти цепочку трех одинаковых последовательных последних элементов в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Найти цепочку трех одинаковых последовательных последних элементов в массиве?
Я подаю на вход массив всех элементов и последний выбранный элемент который нужно проверить  и которого нет еще массиве и проверяю есть ли этот элемент последним или предпоследним. Если да, то это повторение

Есть лучше варианты?

```
  const check =  ({ array, prop1, prop2 } = {}) => {
    if (!Array.isArray(array) || array.length === 0 ) {
        return;
    }

    const lastIndex = array.length - 1;
    const prevIndex = array.length - 2;

    const last = array[lastIndex];

    const prev =  array[prevIndex];

    if (!prev) return;

    const isMatchWithLast = last.prop1 === prop1 && last.prop2 === prop2;
    const isMatchWithPrev = prev.prop1 === prop1 && prev.prop2 === prop2;



    return isMatchWithLast && isMatchWithPrev;
}
```

Comment: Можете показать пример вводных данных и пример выходных?

Comment: "Я подаю на вход массив всех элементов и последний выбранный элемент который нужно проверить". Почему у вас функция от трех аргументов?

Comment: check({ array, '12','23' })
это свойста элемента из массива
элемент в массиве - это объект

Comment: у меня дан массив объектов. и элемент - это элемент из этого массива.онже объект

Comment: но ведь у вас же св-ва передаются, о каком объекте вы вообще говорите? да и параметр у вас один, зачем вам этот объект, если потом все равно разворачиваете?

Comment: ок. можно передавать elem = {prop1: '123', prop2: '124'}
и всеэлементы в массиве array такого вида. поэтому я и проверяю что если эти два свойства совпадают...

Answer (score 1):

Я бы так проверял.

```js
const check =  ({ array, element } = {}) => {
    if (!Array.isArray(array) || array.length <== 1 ) {
        return;
    }

    const lastIndex = array.length - 1;
    const prevIndex = array.length - 2;

    const last = array[lastIndex];

    const prev =  array[prevIndex];
    
    return last === element && prev === element;
}
```

Comment: > проверяю есть ли этот элемент последним или предпоследним. 
У вас же логическое _И_ ( как и у автора почему-то ), наверное стоит поменять на `||`

Comment: @ThisMan ну вопрос звучит по-другому "Найти цепочку трех одинаковых последовательных последних элементов в массиве?"

Comment: в таком случае у вас проверка цепочки из двух элементов